# How to send log entries from non ATG java code to ATG logs

Tags: log4j, weblogic, atg

Our application is running on weblogic and uses ATG also. We have some non-ATG based java components for which we use Log4j for logging and logging happens fine in weblogic server. We are trying to centralize the logging hence we want to send the log entries of non-ATG components to ATG logs too. Is there a way to do that?

Sample code used for weblogic logging:

```
 Logger logger =
 weblogic.logging.log4j.Log4jLoggingHelper.getLog4jServerLogger();
 logger.info("Test message");;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in ATG is to use the ApplicationLogging interface.

Please check this ATG Documentation, it has clear cut code example :-

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s1103loggingwithnonnucleusinstantiate01.html

Regards,
Gaurav Edekar